# V-data-table workaround from Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I'm upgrading an app from vue2 to vue3, same goes for vuetify (2 to 3).
Problem is that Vuetify 3's documentation is incomplete. Specifically [Vue Data Tables](https://next.vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-data-table/). :(

The App I'm working with is full of v-data-table and im incapable of generating the data.

I dont know if a code samples help, any workaround ideais appreciated.

```
<v-data-table
      :headers="someHeaders"
      :items="thisData.something"
      hide-actions
      item-key="id"
    >
      <template #items="something">
        <tr>
          <td>{{ some.item.one| formatItem }}</td>
          <td>{{ some.item.two}}</td>
          <td>{{ some.item.three}}</td>
          <td>{{ some.item.four| function}}%</td>
        </tr>
      </template>
    </v-data-table>
```

thank you!

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. Vuetify is the only thing that's holding me back from upgrading to Vue 3. In case of a production app, I suggest to stick with Vue 2 for now.

Comment: Maybe it's time to switch over to Quasar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up using [EasyDataTable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue3-easy-data-table) which has a very similiar syntax. Worked like a charm. Data sample:

```
<template>
  <EasyDataTable
    :headers="headers"
    :items="items"
  />
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes along and looks at this, v-data-table in Vuetify 3 is still in development (labs) but you can actually use the development version. Follow the [installation instructions](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/labs/introduction/) to load it into your project.